# Subscriber is triggering even it is unsubscribed

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular7, subscription, eventemitter

I have an event emitter and 5 subscriber's in each of the 5 pages say(Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, Page 4, Page 5)

I subscribed for the event on the ngOnInit() and unsubscribe it on ngOnDestroy(),

These pages are actually routed pages , ie only only one page will be loaded to the DOM at once

So my use case is 
Initially i go to Page 1 and triggered the event emitter 
Then i move to Page 2 again triggered the event emitter
I can observe that this event emitter triggered the subscription in both Page 1 and Page 2,

How it is possible because i have already unsubscribed,
How can i fix this ?

```js
ngOnInit() {
this.translationService = this.sharedService.language_english.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.trigger_translation_module(data);
      }
    );
}

 ngOnDestroy() {

    this.translationService.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that angular route changes don't call the destroy lifecycle methods.

Workarounds are discussed in the issue below
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1049

If you don't need to specifically change the service depending on the page you could simply initialise it during your `app.component.ts` constructor instead of within each individual page